# AngularJS - Migrating jQuery functions to angular ones

Tags: angularjs

I am taking over a big (50+ modules) AngularJS project, from another programmer, which did not do it right, so I have several migration questions:

1. There are lots of usages of JS functions like setTimeout and setInterval. It will be very easy to change to $timeout and $interval (because they use the same syntax, so it is just find and replace), but should I bother?
2. The entire project is without services, and all data requests run in the controllerss. Should I make time to create services for all controllers, the most important ones, or none? (I know that "if it works dont fix it", but from your experience does this make your life easier?)
3. The ENTIRE project uses $.ajax, with over a thousand requests. I do not have the time to migrate all requests to use $http, but I will try over time. In the meanwhile, should I create a service like $http_o and replace all "$.ajax(" strings in all files to $http_o, so the service will pretty much get a normal ajax request syntax, and send it using the $http service.
4. Every controller's services are written in a variable name, and not with a string at the start (function($scope) instead of ['$scope', function($scope)). Is there a fast way to change all of them to use the normal syntax, so I can use a minifier, or do I have to do it by hand? Should I do it?

I will obviously try my best to rework modules to use correct MVC and angular rules in my spare time at work, but this will happen way ahead in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It's not as trivial as you might think i.e. `$interval` applies a `$rootScope.$apply()` at end so it will trigger `$digest` cycle, with lots of intervals it might slow down app
2. It's all about readability and maintainability. I'd say yes, do separate services and DRY the application otherwise when you will have to debug it in 3 months time it's going to be hell
3. A smart regex could work for you although the advantage of using `$http` over $.ajax is that you don't have to use tricks to trigger change in view - i.e. manually run $digest or $apply
4. You can do it easily with https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate

Comment: OK. so Ill change the timeouts and intervals, with invokeApply. Ill try to gradualy move everything to services, I will not move current $.ajax requests to $http, and I will read more about ng-annotate. Thanks!

Comment: Well with ng annotate it's fairly simple, first install it with npm and then simple `ng-annotate -a source.js` will do it, eventually pipe to file and that's it :)